# Randomly assigned buttons

Tags: c#, html, wpf, xaml

so this code here dynamically adds buttons to my wpf windows application. I cant think of the way in which I can call buttons which actually runat server because they are randomly added.

```
namespace DynamicButtons
{
    public partial class Window1
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            populateButtons();
        }

        public void populateButtons()
        {
            int xPos;
            int yPos;

            Random ranNum = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Button foo = new Button();
                Style buttonStyle = Window.Resources["CurvedButton"] as Style;

                int sizeValue = ranNum.Next(100);

                foo.Width = sizeValue;
                foo.Height = sizeValue;

                xPos = ranNum.Next(200);
                yPos = ranNum.Next(300);

                foo.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                foo.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                foo.Margin = new Thickness(xPos, yPos, 0, 0);

                foo.Style = buttonStyle;
                foo.Name = "button" + i;

                foo.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(buttonClick);

                LayoutRoot.Children.Add(foo);
           }
        }

        private void buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button clicked = (Button) sender;
            // something like certainWindowsButton((i)<-this has to be based on above code) = clicked.Name(); 
            MessageBox.Show("Button's name is: " + clicked.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Every time the application runs the buttons are randomly assigned, what I want is a way in which I can interact with them from the code behind.

So

```
foo.Name = "button" + i;
```

means when or whichever button is clicked a number is assigned to it but how can I interact with that button in the code?

```
    private void buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button clicked = (Button) sender;
        // something like certainWindowsButton((i)<-this has to be based on above code) = clicked.Name(); 
        MessageBox.Show("Button's name is: " + clicked.Name);
    }
}
```

I hope that makes sense.

To give you a sense of whats happening at design level:

[image]

Each of these grey squares are buttons each button is randomly assigned its designated name and number and each time the application runs these buttons will be reassigned a different number.

I need a way inwhich when a number is assigned to it I can then fire an event for that button clicked.

So randomly a button has been assigned number 1, take this number 1 and then assign it to

```
private void buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 

if
{
    button1_Click = clicked.Name(strip away "button" and make sure the (variableNumber leftover matches button(1)_Click);
}
else 
    button2
```

etc etc

Which then fires my button event:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("yay each randomly assigned button now correlates with a real button event");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `clicked.Name` not give you the name you want? It looks like it should do... The whole point of the sender parameter to an event handler is that it contains the object that triggered the event, ie the button that was clicked...

Comment: yeah but how do you bind button1 to something in the code behind? If I wanted "button1" to open content for example how can I call it in the code behind when button1 is pressed?

Comment: I dont want all the buttons to do the same thing all this does is change the button name displayed when I press a button, if I wanted one button to show a message box but another button to open another window how can I differentiate between the two?

Comment: Well, the very simplest way would just be using a switch statement on the name and in each case call a different method. I'd probably put this in a different method rather that the click event calls for neatness but it should do what you want unless I am missing something.

Comment: As requested I've put an answer in showing you what I mean. Hopefully that makes more sense than my brief explanations. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this more what you're looking for?  This takes each buttonNClick handler and creates a button for it.  This way you don't even need the "i".

```
partial class Window1 {
    void button3Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        //Whatever you want here
    }
    void button2Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        //Whatever you want here
    }
    void button1Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        //Whatever you want here
    }

    public Window1() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        populateButtons();
    }

    public void populateButtons() {
        int xPos;
        int yPos;

        Random ranNum = new Random();
        foreach (var routedEventHandler in new RoutedEventHandler[] { button1Click, button2Click, button3Click }) {
            Button foo = new Button();

            int sizeValue = ranNum.Next(100);

            foo.Width = sizeValue;
            foo.Height = sizeValue;

            xPos = ranNum.Next(200);
            yPos = ranNum.Next(300);

            foo.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            foo.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            foo.Margin = new Thickness(xPos, yPos, 0, 0);

            foo.Click += routedEventHandler;

            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry could you show that within my code and instead of "dowhatyouwant" maybe fire `button1_Click`?

Comment: @Kirsty Not sure what you mean.  You _could_ use the reflection API to do something like (pseudocode) `Reflect.GetMethod(this.Type, "button" + i2 + "_click").Execute();`, but I don't think that's the best option.

Comment: `foo.Name = "button" + i;` It looks like its almost right but this line has problems.

Comment: Do you actually use the Name for anything?  You can get rid of this line if you're not using it for anything else.

Comment: ahh nah this doesnt work after all the buttons become static and lose all the formatting

Comment: @Kirsty I removed the style so it would run on my machine.  Add it back in and you'll get the formatting back.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to choose an action based on the button name the below code may help. Obviously the doAction method calls will change as will your cases but hopefully the code gives you a good enough general idea.

```
    private void buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button clicked = (Button) sender;
        ChooseAction(clicked.Name);
    }

    private void ChooseAction(string buttonName)
    {
        switch(buttonName)
        {
            case "button1": doAction1(); break;
            case "button2": doAction2(); break;
            case "button3": doAction3(); break;
            case "button4": doAction4(); break;
            case "button5": doAction5(); break;
            default: doDefaultAction(); break;
        }
    }

    private void doAction1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("action 1");
    }

    private void doAction2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("action 2");
    }
    private void doAction3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("action 3");
    }
    private void doAction4()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("action 4");
    }
    private void doAction5()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("action 5");
    }

    private void doDefaultAction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("button name not recognised, performing default action");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As lobsterism said, or you could have a list of commands, that you bind randomly to the buttons, instead of any of this. http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-command-bindings-and-custom-commands

here is a verbose sample:

```
public class CoolCommand : ICommand
{
    #region ICommand Members

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
       //do what you want :)
    }

    #endregion
}

var allCommands = new List<ICommand>();
allCommands.Add(new CoolCommand);
allCommands.Add(new OtherCoolCommand);
allCommands.Add(new ThirdCoolCommand);

private void assignButton(button)
{
    var idx = new Random().nextInt(allCommands.Count-1);
    var command = allComands[idx];
    button.Command = command;
    allCommands.remove(command);
}
```