# adding content to a button click in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Why cant I do this in wpf?

```
    button1Click.Content = "Hover over me";
```

or

```
    ToolTip t = new ToolTip();
    t.Content = "Something helpful";
    button1Click.Tooltip = t;
```

I populate my widow with populate buttons on initialization I then have a foreach loop that adds buttons like so:

```
     foreach (var routedEventHandler in new RoutedEventHandler[] { button1Click, button2Click, button3_Click })`
```

Now in this area I apply styles to the buttons all in one go like so:

```
public void populateButtons()
        {
            double xPos;
            double yPos;


            Random ranNum = new Random();
            foreach (var routedEventHandler in new RoutedEventHandler[] { button1Click, button2Click, button3_Click })
            {

                Button foo = new Button();



                Style buttonStyle = Window.Resources["CurvedButton"] as Style;
                int sizeValue = 100;

                foo.Width = sizeValue;
                foo.Height = sizeValue;

                xPos = ranNum.Next(200);
                yPos = ranNum.Next(250);


                foo.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                foo.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                foo.Margin = new Thickness(xPos, yPos, 0, 0);
                foo.Style = buttonStyle;

                foo.Click += routedEventHandler;

                LayoutRoot.Children.Add(foo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try this:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Button)sender).ToolTip = t;
    }
```

It only activates when a button is pressed? (Thanks @H.B)

However when I paste the tooltip code in my populate buttons:

```
        Random ranNum = new Random();
        foreach (var routedEventHandler in new RoutedEventHandler[] { button1Click, button2Click, button3_Click })
        {

            Button foo = new Button();
            ToolTip t = new ToolTip();
            t.Content = "Something helpful";
            foo.ToolTip = t;
```

It works? But the problem is that doing it this way sets all buttons with the same tooltip and or button content! which I dont want, but I cant find a way around it?

So to summarize I can either set all buttons with the same tooltip message or button content within "populateButtons()" or I can only set tooltips and button content when the button has been pressed.

Is there no method possible that can add content to a named button?

Like my initial attempt:

```
button1Click.Content = "Home Button";
```

or

```
button1Click.ToolTip = "Hover over me";
```

Why on earth cant you set content and tooltips for specific buttons on initialization?

Comment: Why in the world would one iterate over some collection of handlers like that i wonder...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843718/randomly-assigned-buttons you can find the reason here @H.B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go this route then you can add a handler for Loaded event:

```
foo.Click += routedEventHandler;
foo.Loaded += routedEventHandler;
```

And then you have something like:

```
void button2Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RoutedEvent == FrameworkElement.LoadedEvent)
        {
            ToolTip t = new ToolTip();
            t.Content = "Something helpful";
            ((Button)sender).ToolTip = t;
            return;
        }
        //Logic for handling button clicks goes here
        MessageBox.Show("action 2");
    }
```

Comment: if you do that all buttons are fired straight away on load, which means if I add a messagebox to all or some or even just one all buttons containing the messagebox are fired upon loading the form.

Comment: Yes you are overloading the event handler.  Not ideal but does the job.  I have updated the code

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning the tooltip in the handler, so how should anything happen?

```
((Button)sender).ToolTip = t;
```

Comment: I have updated my question this might provide more clarity. Once I read it over I realised it only made sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to have different "types" of buttons, each one with a different Click handler and a different Tooltip.

If that's the case, You could create different classes deriving from Button (e.g. HelpfulButton, UnhelpfulButton... choose good names please :) ) and in their constructor  assign the handler and tooltip.

Then, in the main code, you could loop through the different classes and add instances of them directly to the main canvas.

Another possible option is to create different "template" buttons using commands and copy the properties from them instead of subclassing Button. Something like this:

```
Button helpfulTemplate = new Button { ToolTip = "blah" };
helpfulTemplate.Command = HelpfulCommand;

Button unhelpfulTemplate = new Button { ToolTip = "bloh" };
unhelpfulTemplate.Command = UnhelpfulCommand;

foreach(var template in new Button[] {helpfulTemplate, unhelpfulTemplate})
{
     var newCopy = new Button();
     //etc.
     newCopy.ToolTip = template.ToolTip;
     newCopy.Command = template.Command;
}
```

Comment: The way I had it in my foreach randomly creates and places 3 buttons on the main form all I want to do is create custom tooltips and button names for them. This method stops me calling those three buttons because they are now not named and the command still only generalizes on the buttons its not specific so button 1 cant say hello on it without all the rest of the buttons saying hello. ALso I cant convert method group to ICommand?